# Configuring Drive SDK for mobile access

Tags: google-drive-api

We have an app that integrates with google drive SDK, and open/new URLs are configured in the API console, working well on the desktop. The "Mobile Browser Support" checkbox is ticked. Still, when I open the Google Drive web page from a mobile browser (Ipad), clicking on a file link downloads the file instead of opening our application in the browser. Any idea if this is a config problem or a bug in the mobile Drive UI?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried, on the mobile Google Drive website, a file is opened with your application instead of being downloaded only if the file has the mime-type of your application. This mime type looks like the following:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.nnnnnnnnnn
```

You can find it by requesting information about your app using the API [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps/list